# Extend Teams App to outlook and office not able to reach app after certain time

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-teams

We are able to see the app working in teams and outlook, the app working only for some time and it crashes , the app is staying for around a minute and it is unable to reach.
[image: can not reach the app]

Followed the [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/m365-apps/prerequisites) as well not sure why the app seems to crash after certain time

Comment: Most likely cause - you're not properly initializing your app. Make sure you're calling `app.initialize` and if you opted into native loading indicator flow also `app.notifySuccess` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/content-page?tabs=teamsjs-v2#show-a-native-loading-indicator)

Comment: Can you see anything in the console logs. Please share the logs when the app crashes?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, it helped, I removed notigySuccess() by mistake. this was the issue